# window.location.href on thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in my Thymeleaf template but it does not work properly since this is the location generated

```
deviceevent/@%7B/deviceevent/list/%7Bid%7D(id=$%7BdeviceEvent.id%7D)%7D
```

in the template

```
<tr th:each="deviceEvent : ${deviceEvents}"  onclick="window.location.href = '@{/deviceevent/list/{id}(id=${deviceEvent.id})}'" >
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thymeleaf doesn't evaluate attributes unless they are prefixed with `th`.  In this case, `th:onclick`.  The complete string should look like this:

```
th:onclick="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/deviceevent/list/{id}(id=${deviceEvent.id})} + '\''"
```